# How to disable disk automount under /Volumes in macOS?

Tags: macos, ssd, mount

I have a PCIe SSD in my Mac Pro 2019. Using the `vifs` command, I have added this line to `/etc/fstab` in order to mount the drive to `/var/my-server`:

```
UUID=B3CDE3B6-C597-407B-8A43-A2324C50427C /var/my-server apfs rw
```

This seems to work, and my disk is mounted to `/var/my-server` and can be accessed there via a bash terminal. However, I've noticed that the disk is still being mounted to the macOS default location as well, `/Volumes/Server SSD`. Is it possible to tell the OS not to mount the drive to `/Volumes/Server SSD`?

Comment: I have no clue about vifs, so not sure if this will work or conflict, but the standard way to prevent auto-mount is using `/private/etc/fstab` Add a line, `[UUID] none auto noauto`

Answer (score 0):

A disk can only be mounted once.  So `/Volumes/Server SSD` is probably a phantom.  I would double check that it is really being mounted in two places.
I've set up many machines with the `/Users` mounted with a volume and have never needed to do anything special to prevent it from showing up under `/Volumes`

I'd check these;

- what does `df` show?
- what does `mount` show
- what does `diskutil list` show

I will warn you, `apfs` is a funny beast and creates a container partition and then "synthesizes" a virtual disk inside that partition, which it can then create multiple apfs volumes.  So you may be seeing other partitions from the container drive in `/Volumes`

This is what my system shows (although my additional drive is only HFS):

**df**

```
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused               ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk2s1   233Gi  184Gi   47Gi    80% 1461865 9223372036853313942    0%   /
devfs          193Ki  193Ki    0Bi   100%     666                   0  100%   /dev
/dev/disk2s4   233Gi  1.0Gi   47Gi     3%       1 9223372036854775806    0%   /private/var/vm
map -hosts       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0                   0  100%   /net
map auto_home    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0                   0  100%   /home
map -fstab       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0                   0  100%   /Network/Servers
/dev/disk3s2    16Ti  8.7Ti  7.3Ti    55%   21031          4294946248    0%   /Volumes/Obord
/dev/disk1s2   1.4Ti   37Gi  1.3Ti     3%     732          4294966547    0%   /mnt
```

You can see that `disk1s2 (/mnt)` is only showing once.

**mount**

```
/dev/disk2s1 on / (apfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
/dev/disk2s4 on /private/var/vm (apfs, local, noexec, journaled, noatime, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
map -fstab on /Network/Servers (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
/dev/disk3s2 on /Volumes/Obord (hfs, NFS exported, local, journaled, noowners)
/dev/disk1s2 on /mnt (hfs, local, journaled)
```

Again just the `/mnt` mount and no other `disk1` Volumes.

**diskutil list**

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *250.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         249.8 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.5 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Users                   1.5 TB     disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk1s3

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +249.8 GB   disk2
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume SSDZero                 197.2 GB   disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 22.0 MB    disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                512.1 MB   disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk2s4

/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *17.6 TB    disk3
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Obord                   17.6 TB    disk3s2
```

From this confusing partition layout you will notice that the system was first installed on a spinning 1.5TB drive (hence the EFI and recovery partitions) then upgraded with a 250G SSD and converted to `apfs` the 1.5TB drive was then cleared and renamed to Users, it's temporarily mounted on `/mnt`.  You'll notice that `disk2` is a virtual drive with 4 volumes.  This is like Apple's version of LVM for Linux but specifically for `apfs` Apple has more volume management commands under CoreStorage, see `diskutil coreStorage` which is used to "merge" the two partitions on a fusion drive.

I'd love to hear how it goes.

Mark